# Mudar "copy" para "copied" no clipboard.js após clique

Tags: javascript, área-de-transferência

Estou tentando fazer o clipboard.js mudar o botão de copiar de "COPY" para "COPIED" após o clique sem perder a função que ele tem que seleciona o código alvo.

Será que alguém saberia como devo fazer?

```js
! function() {
  for (var a = document.getElementsByTagName("pre"), b = document.getElementById("paste-content"), c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
    var d = a[c].children[0].className.indexOf("language-");
    if (0 === d) {
      var e = document.createElement("button");
      e.className = "copy-button", e.textContent = "COPY", a[c].appendChild(e)
    }
  }
  var f = new Clipboard(".copy-button", {
    target: function(a) {
      return a.previousElementSibling
    }
  })
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.7.1/clipboard.min.js"></script>


<pre class="input button border"><code class="language-less" id="dialog_coupon_code_1">CODE 1</code></pre>
<pre class="input button border"><code class="language-less" id="dialog_coupon_code_2">CODE 2</code></pre>
<pre class="input button border"><code class="language-less" id="dialog_coupon_code_3">CODE 3</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

Para atualizar o botão, adicione uma função de *callback* no evento `success`. Esse evento irá retornar (como parâmetro) o elemento clicado e com o acesso a esse elemento, você poderá alterar o valor da propriedade `innerHTML` ou `textContent`.

```js
! function() {
  for (var a = document.getElementsByTagName("pre"), b = document.getElementById("paste-content"), c = 0; c < a.length; c++) {
    var d = a[c].children[0].className.indexOf("language-");
    if (0 === d) {
      var e = document.createElement("button");
      e.className = "copy-button", e.textContent = "COPY", a[c].appendChild(e)
    }
  }
  var f = new Clipboard(".copy-button", {
    target: function(a) {
      return a.previousElementSibling
    }
  })

  /* Adiciona o evento de sucesso */
  f.on('success', function(e) {

    /* Acessa o elemento (Botão) e altera o nome */
    e.trigger.innerHTML = "Copied!"

    /* Código Adcional para voltar o nome original */
    setTimeout(function() {
      e.trigger.innerHTML = "COPY"
      e.clearSelection();
    }, 3000);
  });

  /*
   * (Opcional)
   * Adiciona o evento de falha
   */
  f.on('error', function(e) {

    /* Acessa o elemento (Botão) e altera o nome */
    e.trigger.innerHTML = "Not Copied!";
    
    console.log( `Action: ${e.action}` );
    console.log( `Trigger: ${e.trigger}` );

    /* Código Adcional para voltar o nome original */
    setTimeout(function() {
      e.trigger.innerHTML = "COPY"
      e.clearSelection();
    }, 3000);
  });
}();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.7.1/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<pre class="input button border">
  <code class="language-less" id="dialog_coupon_code_1">CODE 1</code>
</pre>

<pre class="input button border">
  <code class="language-less" id="dialog_coupon_code_2">CODE 2</code>
</pre>

<pre class="input button border">
  <code class="language-less" id="dialog_coupon_code_3">CODE 3</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Excelente, você também poderia implementar o error acaso ocorra algum erro devido a alguma configuração do navegador, ainda sim +1 pois já esta uma otima resposta.

Comment: Perfeito, era exatamente isso. Obrigado!